# Given a set of numbers, is there a quick way to find the two numbers which their product is closest to a given number?

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose I have a set of triangle numbers `A = {1, 3, 6, 10 ...}` (2000 items)

I want to find the pair of numbers in `AxA` (i.e. 1*3, 1*6, 3*6..., `a*b`,...) where the product `a*b` is closest to `N`. (`N = 2000000`).

What I tried was to generate the pairs of numbers and then get `abs(N - a*b)` and sort, and find first pair. But I find it too slow.

Is technique I can use here to easily arrive at an answer?

Comment: Have you tried using the fact that triangle numbers can be represented as their indices, and hence you could minimize a quadratic in logarithmic time by using binary search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no one has mentioned using triangular number properties yet: 
Triangular numbers are defined as: $$T_n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$
Using this, product of two, $T_n \cdot T_k$ would be 
$$T(n,k) = T_n\cdot T_k = \frac{nk + n + k + 1}{4}$$
This can be calculated in $O(1)$ time. 
Now set n = n, k = 1, where n = largest index available. 
 
Now:

1. Record $|N-T(n,k)|$ and if it is the minimum, store the values of n,k.
2. If T(n,k) > N, set n as $\frac{n+k}{2}$
3. If T(n,k) < N, set k as $\frac{n+k}{2}$
4. If T(n,k) = N, you have your values.
   After this, you will have the index values of your triangle numbers. You can reverse calculate $T_n$ and $T_k$. 
   Since, the entire algorithm is essentially two binary searches, the time complexity is $O(log(n))$

Comment: This is a great method. However, note that there might not be values for `n`, `k` such that `T(n,k) == N`. The idea is to get as close to `N` as possible.

Comment: @nakiya  Thus there was the first step...  every time you change the value of n or k, you find the absolute difference between T and N, see if it is smaller than all other T’s so far, and keep track of it

Comment: Can the same time complexity be maintained? What would be the stopping condition of the search?

Comment: @nakiya when n>= k should be the stoping condition. Yes, the complexity should be log(n)... as I said, two binary searches at each stage of the binary search you do constant operations.

Answer (score 1):

If the number of elements in the given set is $n$, then you can use hashing to obtain a $O(n)$ solution for the related problem of deciding if there exists such a pair in the given set. Below, I give the high level pseudocode of the algorithm. This should give you an idea of how to solve your problem.

1. Let A be the given array of elements. Create an empty hash table H.
2. for i = $0$ to $n$:

   (i) If A[i] == $0$ && N == $0$: return true.

   (ii) Else If N % A[i] == $0$ && N/A[i] exists in H: return true.

   (iii) Insert A[i] into H.
3. Return false

Comment: I followed something similar to this in the end. Note that the product can be close to `N` and not exactly equal to it. So, then a sorted hash table is needed.

Comment: @nakiya exactly!!

Answer (score 0):

If your numbers are sorted, you could "prefilter" some options by doing something like this:

1. Pick a number x in the sorted set A.
2. For different values of y in A, calculate d = abs(N- xy). Since the set is sorted, d should decrease until you find the optimal value of y, then it starts increasing.
3. When d increases stop iterating  on values of y, pick the next x and start all over again with the values of y.

I think my answer is rather obvious but it will certainly help if you are generating all pairs before calculating the distance, which you don't need to do.